# jQuery loop scroller - need the code to loop the scroller back to the beginning onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a scroller that uses a left and right arrow to scroll through each div. What I need is some sort of javascript or jquery that will allow me to loop back to the beginning of the slide by hitting the "next" or "previous" buttons when the slide reaches the end. Here is my code so far. I know there is some type of loop code but I don't know how to implement it to make it work. Besides jQuery, I don't use any type of scroller/carousel js code added within the file.

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/aj3ub/

JS

```
//this is used to call open the ID that contains where the scrolling starts

function overviper() {
    el = document.getElementById("overviper");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}


// these are used to click through left and right within the scroller


$(function () {  // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#rightbox, #leftbox").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "rightbox" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".all").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '990' }, 1000);
    });

});


$(function () {  // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#rightbox1, #leftbox1").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "rightbox1" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".all").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '985' }, 1000);
    });

});

$(function () {  // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#rightbox2, #leftbox2").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "rightbox2" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".all").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '985' }, 1000);
    });

});

$(function () {  // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#rightbox3, #leftbox3").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "rightbox3" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".all").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '985' }, 1000);
    });

});

$(function () {  // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#rightbox4, #leftbox4").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "rightbox4" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".all").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '985' }, 1000);
    });

});

$(function () {  // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#rightbox5, #leftbox5").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "rightbox5" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".all").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '985' }, 1000);
    });

});

$(function () {  // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#rightbox6, #leftbox6").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "rightbox6" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".all").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '985' }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: FYI you don't need to wrap each single click handler in a DOM ready - put them all in a single DOM ready handler. Also your fiddle is next to useless as the images are not accessible so nothing can be seen.

Comment: Actually, I have to create for each div because each panel holds the same ID's and I have to change the ID name.

Comment: You should never duplicate an ID on a page.